# when we close the "Choose an account" page using "X" button then "popup_closed_by_user" error thrown in console .Using "angular5-social-login" package

Tags: angular5, google-signin

After clicking "Login with Google",button when user close the "Choose an account" page using "X" button then "popup_closed_by_user" error thrown in console .
Can you please suggest how to handle it .
I am using "angular5-social-login" package

```ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService, GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angular5-social-login';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-google-login',
  templateUrl: './google-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./google-login.component.scss']
})
export class GoogleLoginComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private socialAuthService: AuthService) { }


  public googleSignIn() {

    let socialPlatformProvider;
    socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;


    try{
    this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(res => this.signInSuccessHandler(res), err => this.signInErrorHandler(err));
    }
    catch(error ){
      console.log("Pop up closed");
    } 


    } 
    private signInErrorHandler(err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }

    private signInSuccessHandler(res) {
      console.log("Google sign in data : ", res);
      const jsonUserData = JSON.stringify(res);
      console.log('Google user details in JSON format: ' + jsonUserData);
    }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

`